# How to keep the common thing between 2 SCSS rules into a single rule and create a new one with the difference

Tags: sass

I have two `div` that have a lot of inputs inside them.

One of them uses only the `PrelimsSpecificsSegButtons` and the other one uses `SliderAcuityAnyButtons` as apperance-class

The only difference between this classes is that

- SliderAcuityAnyButtons uses `&:nth-child(6n+18)`
- PrelimsSpecificsSegButtons uses `&:nth-child(6n+0)`

Everything else is exactly the same.

Is there a way to factor what is common into one class and just have what is different in another to avoid all this duplicate CSS instructions

```
@include field-radio-appearance($appearance-class: "PrelimsSpecificsSegButtons") {

  #{$field-state-disabled-selector} {

    opacity: .6;

    &:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    #{$field-textbox-selector} {
      border: 1px transparent;
      background: none;
      cursor: default;
      color: #7E7E7E;
    }
  }

  &:not(#{$field-state-disabled-selector}) {
    &:not(.VerticalOptions) {
      #{$field-option-selector} {
        &.radio-inline {

          &:hover {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #e6e6e8);
          }

          #{$field-state-active-selector} {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
            border: 1px solid #818181;
            z-index: 2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:not(.VerticalOptions):not(.OrderActivity) {

    #{$field-option-selector} {
      &.radio-inline {

        @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #cdced1);
        color: #333333;
        margin-right: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #b5b6ba;
        padding: 1px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:23px;
        &:first-child {
          border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
          margin-left: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
          border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
        }
        &:nth-child(6n+0) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(1) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(2) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(3) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(4) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(5) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        #{$field-state-active-selector} {
          @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
          border: 1px solid #818181;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        #{$field-option-label-selector} {

          padding: 0;

          &:before, &:after {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include field-radio-appearance($appearance-class: "SliderAcuityAnyButtons") {

  #{$field-state-disabled-selector} {

    opacity: .6;

    &:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    #{$field-textbox-selector} {
      border: 1px transparent;
      background: none;
      cursor: default;
      color: #7E7E7E;
    }
  }

  &:not(#{$field-state-disabled-selector}) {
    &:not(.VerticalOptions) {
      #{$field-option-selector} {
        &.radio-inline {

          &:hover {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #e6e6e8);
          }

          #{$field-state-active-selector} {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
            border: 1px solid #818181;
            z-index: 2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:not(.VerticalOptions):not(.OrderActivity) {

    #{$field-option-selector} {
      &.radio-inline {

        @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #cdced1);
        color: #333333;
        margin-right: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #b5b6ba;
        padding: 1px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:23px;
        &:first-child {
          border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
          margin-left: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
          border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
        }
        &:nth-child(6n+18) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(1) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(2) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(3) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(4) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(5) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        #{$field-state-active-selector} {
          @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
          border: 1px solid #818181;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        #{$field-option-label-selector} {

          padding: 0;

          &:before, &:after {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I asked the question, I also found the answer:

1. Keep the common parts in one rule now name `SliderButtons`
2. Create a new rule called `PrelimExam_HideButtons` that uses the `nth-child(6n+0)`
3. Create a new rule called `SliderAcuityAny_HideButtons` that uses the `nth-child(6n+18)`

Then modify the DIVs so that they have now two classes, the common and the specific:

- DivA has apperance-classes: `SliderButtons PrelimExam_HideButtons`
- DivB has apperance-classes: `SliderButtons SliderAcuityAny_HideButtons`

Here is the SCSS code:

```
@include field-radio-appearance($appearance-class: "SliderButtons") {

  #{$field-state-disabled-selector} {

    opacity: .6;

    &:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    #{$field-textbox-selector} {
      border: 1px transparent;
      background: none;
      cursor: default;
      color: #7E7E7E;
    }
  }

  &:not(#{$field-state-disabled-selector}) {
    &:not(.VerticalOptions) {
      #{$field-option-selector} {
        &.radio-inline {

          &:hover {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #e6e6e8);
          }

          #{$field-state-active-selector} {
            @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
            border: 1px solid #818181;
            z-index: 2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &:not(.VerticalOptions):not(.OrderActivity) {

    #{$field-option-selector} {
      &.radio-inline {

        @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #f8f8f8, $G2: #cdced1);
        color: #333333;
        margin-right: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #b5b6ba;
        padding: 1px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: -1px;
        height:23px;
        &:first-child {
          border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
          margin-left: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
          border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
        }

        &:nth-last-child(1) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(2) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        &:nth-last-child(3) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(4) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        &:nth-last-child(5) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        }
        #{$field-state-active-selector} {
          @include linear-gradient($pos: top, $G1: #cdced1, $G2: #b5b6ba);
          border: 1px solid #818181;
          z-index: 2;
        }

        #{$field-option-label-selector} {

          padding: 0;

          &:before, &:after {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
@include field-radio-appearance($appearance-class: "PrelimExam_HideButtons") {

   &:not(.VerticalOptions):not(.OrderActivity) {

    #{$field-option-selector} {
      &.radio-inline {

        &:nth-child(6n+0) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


@include field-radio-appearance($appearance-class: "SliderAcuityAny_HideButtons") {

   &:not(.VerticalOptions):not(.OrderActivity) {

    #{$field-option-selector} {
      &.radio-inline {

        &:nth-child(6n+18) {
            background: white !important;
            opacity: 0;
            .p-option-label
            {
                cursor: context-menu !important;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            pointer-events: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```